# Remove or skip element in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a troble with IQueryable which is being retunem from below query:

```
var userTasks = from tasks in context.Tasks
                                join projects in context.Projects
                                on tasks.ProjectId equals projects.ProjectId
                                join userProjects in context.UserProjects
                                on projects.ProjectId equals userProjects.ProjectId
                                join users in context.UserProjects
                                on userProjects.UserId equals users.UserId
                                select new
                                {
                                    TaskId = tasks.TaskId,
                                    Name = tasks.Name,
                                    Status = tasks.Status
                                };
```

After I get my Tasks in IQueryable I must loop through each element

```
foreach (object task in userTasks)
{
var taskId = userTasks.Where(t => t.TaskId == projectId).FirstOrDefault().TaskId;
//other operations
}
```

While I am using FirstOrDefault I am always getting the same taskId. IQuyeryable doesnt not have method Remove. How then I can skip element I`ve already took?

Comment: Won't that just make `taskId` equal to `projectId` or throw a null reference exception if there isn't a match?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do in the last query.

Comment: Of course its not too much for today, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach (var task in userTasks)
{
     var taskId = task.TaskId
}
```

Right now you are taking the first item in your query result for each item you got there, which is obviously always the same item.

Comment: Omfg it was so easy, too much coding for today thanks :)

Comment: happens to everybody

Answer (score 3):

You meant to take only the tasks equal to the task id.

```
foreach (var task in userTasks.Where(t => t.TaskId == projectId))
{
    var taskId = task.TaskId; // Always the same task.
    //other operations
}
```

If you want to query the entire results, then:

```
foreach (var task in userTasks)
{
    var taskId = task.TaskId;
    //other operations
}
```